# How can I tell when the Timed Attack moment is?

Tags: sea-of-stars

Sea of Stars uses one of my favorite features of Super Mario RPG that I wish more RPGs would use: Timed Hits. But, also like Super Mario RPG, it's not always obvious exactly when you're supposed to trigger it. Most attacks aren't an issue, it's pretty obvious when the weapon makes contact with the enemy. But as I'm progressing and unlocking new skills and combos, I'm left guessing for some of them.

For example, Garl's Nourish ability. Garl reaches into his bag, rummages twice, pulls out an apple, and throws it at the selected character. For the first few times, I tried to press the button when the apple hit the character it's intended for (or Garl eats it himself). That wasn't it. Then I thought it might be the moment the apple is thrown (maybe throwing it harder heals better?). Eventually I figured out the proper moment is when he pulls out the apple (or a few frames before) and you know it works because Garl pulls out a sandwich instead.

I am also struggling to find the "magic moment" for the Mending Light combo and Zale's Healing Light.

Am I missing something in-game signaling which instant is the moment for the Timed Hit? Am I supposed to discover it through trial and error? I know there's an artifact that helps clarify when I successfully hit a Timed Hit but I'm not having issues knowing when I succeed.

Comment: There unfortunately isn't an indication. Some skills mention that "when timed, X happens" but nothing mentions timing.

Comment: There is a relic available from the start that gives an indication when you hit the timed hit. The name escapes me now however.   It does not give any other indications however. But I found it does help learning the timings.  
 



As for Zales Healing Light the timed hit is just before the "sparkly ball" at the end of the spiral animation "explodes".   Combos ususally uses similar timings as regular skills where applicable.